# Advertencia al subir APK a la Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

[image]

Me sale este mensaje al querer lanzar la version de produccion de mi Aplicacion, que alguien me diga que es lo que tengo que hacer

Comment: a mi me pasa lo mismo. Quiero subir mi app y me sale el mensajito ese de app bundle. Es una advertencia, si, pero no me deja continuar. A causa de ese mensaje no puedo publicar, ya que el botón para enviarla a producción me sale inactivo. La cuestión es que la he creado con app maker now, y no sé muy bien como funciona android studio ni se mucho sobre programación. Help me!!!

Answer (score 2):

Eso es porque estás tratando de subir la APK directa, actualmente Google recomienda (aunque mayormente obliga) a utilizar el "appbundle" para subir aplicaciones, por lo tanto, te recomiendo generar el appbundle de tu aplicación. No sé si estás utilizando algún SDK como Flutter o ReactNative, o directamente Android de forma nativa, por ende no te puedo indicar el código especifico para ello.

Al menos para flutter, el codigo es el siguiente (ejecutable por consola):

```
flutter build appbundle --release --target-platform android-arm64
```

Comment: Hola, la imagen que muestra el usuario es de un .apk nativo al subirlo a Google Play.Console.

Comment: Si, es por eso que menciono que en la Google Play ahora fomentan el uso de appbundle para subir una aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es un error, como indicas es una "Advertencia" por lo cual **puedes subir tu .apk a [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) sin ningún problema**.

Pero **lo ideal es "optimizar" tu aplicación ya que indica que contiene recursos que pueden ser optimizados**.

Para esto puedes usar el  [**Android App Bundle**](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle) el cual incluye las siguientes características y beneficios:

> **Dynamic Delivery**: el nuevo modelo de publicación de aplicaciones de Google Play, denominado Dynamic Delivery, utiliza su paquete de
>   aplicaciones para generar y publicar APK optimizados para la
>   configuración de dispositivos de cada usuario, por lo que descargan
>   solo el código y los recursos que necesitan para ejecutar su
>   aplicación. Por ejemplo, no necesita cadenas de otros idiomas si ha
>   configurado el inglés como idioma predeterminado.
>
> **No es necesario administrar manualmente múltiples APK**: ya no tiene que compilar, firmar y administrar múltiples APK para admitir
>   diferentes dispositivos, y los usuarios obtienen descargas más
>   pequeñas y más optimizadas. Por ejemplo, ahora no tiene que crear
>   múltiples APK para dispositivos con diferentes resoluciones de
>   pantalla.
>
> **Módulo de características dinámicas**: estos módulos contienen características y activos que puede decidir no incluir cuando los
>   usuarios descargan e instalan su aplicación por primera vez. Usando
>   Play Core Library, su aplicación puede solicitar luego descargar esos
>   módulos como APK de características dinámicas. Por ejemplo, la función
>   de videollamada y los filtros de la cámara se pueden descargar más
>   tarde bajo demanda.
>
> **Tamaño de APK reducido**: mediante el uso del mecanismo Split APK (explicado más adelante), Google Play puede dividir una aplicación
>   grande en paquetes más pequeños y discretos que se instalan en el
>   dispositivo del usuario según sea necesario. En promedio, las
>   aplicaciones publicadas con paquetes de aplicaciones son un 20% más
>   pequeñas en tamaño.

De esta forma puedes crear el App Bundle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que tal, entiendo que es una recomendación, pero en mi caso no me deja seguir sin antes corregir lo que la advertencia indica.